# TextBox ClassModule - Change backgroundcolor only on a real value change

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, userform

I have a Userform with multiple Controls (Textbox). Those Textboxes will be populated by selecting a ListBox item.
When initializing the UserForm those TextBoxes will be assigned to a specific Class which handles them.

I want VBA to change the background color of those textboxes only when a real change of the value was performed. What I have is that the BackgroundColor is always changed as soon as a change was performed, but that's not what I want.

Example #1:
**Textbox value before change:** "test"
**Textbox value after change:** "test2"
--> BackgroundColor should be changed

Example #2:
**Textbox value before change:** "test"
**Textbox value after change:** "test bla" but then I am typing "test" again.
--> BackgroundColor should not be changed, because initial Value is in the TextBox again.

What I have so far:

```
' **************************************************************
'  Module:  clsTextbox  Typ = Class Module
' **************************************************************

Public WithEvents mTextBoxs As MSForms.TextBox

Private Sub mTextBoxs_Change()

If mTextBoxs.Text = strInitialVal Then
Reset_BackColor
Else
    mTextBoxs.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 153)
End If
End Sub

Public Sub Reset_BackColor()
    mTextBoxs.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
End Sub
```

---

```
' **************************************************************
'  Module:  frmEmployee  Type = Userform
' **************************************************************
Dim arrLabels() As New clsLabel, UBoundarrLabels As Integer
Dim arrTextBoxs() As New clsTextbox, UBoundarrTextBoxs As Integer

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim Ctrl As Control, obLabel As MSForms.Label, obTextbox As MSForms.TextBox
    tblName = "tblMitarbeiter"
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Mitarbeiter")

    i = 0
    For Each Ctrl In Me.Controls
        If Left(Ctrl.Name, 7) = "TextBox" Then
            i = i + 1
            ReDim Preserve arrTextBoxs(i)
            Set obTextbox = Me.Controls("TextBox" & i)
            Set arrTextBoxs(i).mTextBoxs = obTextbox
        End If
    Next Ctrl

    ' Fill Listbox1 with values (Vorname & Nachname) from Table [tblMitarbeiter]
    Dim lngLastRow As Long: lngLastRow = getListLastRow(ws, tblName)
    Dim vArrListBox1() As Variant
    ReDim vArrListBox1(0 To lngLastRow - 1, 0 To 2)
    For j = 1 To lngLastRow
        vArrListBox1(j - 1, 0) = ws.ListObjects("tblMitarbeiter").DataBodyRange(j, 1).Value
        vArrListBox1(j - 1, 1) = ws.ListObjects("tblMitarbeiter").DataBodyRange(j, 2).Value
        vArrListBox1(j - 1, 2) = ws.ListObjects("tblMitarbeiter").DataBodyRange(j, 3).Value
    Next j

    For t = 1 To 4
        Me.Controls("TextBox" & t) = vArrEmployee(t - 1)
    Next t

    strInitialVal = Me.Controls("TextBox2")

End Sub
```

**My thoughts are:**
As you can see I tried to declare a public variable (strInitialVal) in a Module which gets the initial value of a textbox (e.g. TextBox2) and when performing the mTextBoxs_Change() Event it checks whether the  strInitialVal is the same as the value in the Textbox and so on.
--> this works, but only for a 1:1 relation of the variable and a textbox.

How can I manage to load all textbox values into an Array? and Check the values in the TextBox Class afterwards.

If you need more information please let me know. I hope I did not violate any SO-rules.

Comment: Store your initial value in the .Tag property of the TextBox,  (or in a custom property in your class)  it's easier to compare it with the actual value. The Change-Event is triggered every-time you type in your TextBox, so the Afterupdate or Exit-event are better used (but cannot be used by WithEvents.

Comment: so simple, so good! the .Tag property is a very good idea! thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use collections to hold your textboxes.
After option explicit, declare these collections
    `Private ColTxtBox As New Collection`

Then when dynamically creating textboxes, here is one example:

```
`'Create Unit size; textbox
Set TxtBox = New DynamicTxtbox
TxtBox.Row = FormRows
TxtBox.Column = A_Deliv.F_UnitSize
Call TxtBox.InitText(frm_delivery.Frame1, "txtbox" & TxtBox.Row) 'this is the 
constructor
ColTxtBox.Add TxtBox`
```

However, if you already created all textboxes on your form and they are fixed, it is sufficient to run through all controls and add these to your collection (if it's a textbox!). Then in your textbox class, you can easily loop through all your texboxes - and access their current values with something like

```
`Private Sub mTextBoxs_Change()
    For Each TxtBox In ColTxtBox
      If InStr(Me.Value,TxtBox.Value) > 0 Then
        Reset_BackColor
      Else 
        mTextBoxs.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 153)
      End If
    Next TxtBox
 EndS Sub`
```

Comment: thx. i didn't get the first part but the second one i might understand. but what happens if let's say 4 values are collected and i change txtbox2 value to something else but this equals a value in the collection, from let's say txtbox4, then the class would recognize it as 'no change' right?

Comment: Ok, thanks. But realized it via the KeyUp Event and detecting whether "Tab Key" was pressed and immediately delcare the public textbox value and also a MouseDown Event in case the user focused the Textbox via left-mouse click and declaring the same as above.

Comment: Try to add the sub mTextBox_Change() like in the example. Does this work?